# "Interacción fallida" al seleccionar un botón en discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Estoy intentando añadir un comando a mi bot de discord que agregue botones personalizados a un mensaje.

He conseguido que el comando añada el botón, pero cuando el usuario lo selecciona desde la aplicación de discord, a este le aparece el error "Interacción fallida" mientras que a mi en la terminal no me aparece ningún error.

No consigo entender a qué se debe esto. Este es el comando:

```
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
async def ticket_button(ctx: commands.Context, embed_id: str, label: str, color: str):
    #Diccionario con colores
    colors = {
        "blue": discord.ButtonStyle.blue,
        "red": discord.ButtonStyle.red,
        "grey": discord.ButtonStyle.grey,
        "green": discord.ButtonStyle.green
    }

    #Obtenemos el canal configurado para recibir el ticket del usuario
    with open("data/server.json", "r") as f:
        ch_ticket = json.load(f)
        try:
            ch_ticket[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]
        except KeyError:
            await ctx.send("Lo siento, no has configurado el canal de ticket :(")
            return

    #Creamos un boton
    button= discord.ui.Button(style=colors[color], label=label)

    #Obtenemos el mensaje
    message = await ctx.message.channel.fetch_message(embed_id)
    embed = message.embeds[0]
    components = message.components
    if len(components) == 0:
        await message.edit(embed=embed, components=[button])
        return

    components = [button, *components]

    await message.edit(embed=embed, components=components)
    
    while True:
        res = await bot.wait_for(event="button_click")
        await res.respond(
            type=discord.InteractionType.ChannelMessageWithSource,
            content="Hola baby 7u7!"
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso el error "Interacción fallida" se debe a que no se está ejecutando nada al seleccionar el discord desde la aplicación de discord. El fallo está en la siguiente línea:

```
res = await bot.wait_for(event="button_click")
```

Se está intentando esperar al evento "on_button_click", pero dicho evento no existe (no aparece en la [documentación](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference)), así que no se está ejecutando nada. Como no hay ningún evento apropiado para esta tarea, `wait_for()` no es el método apropiado para la misma.

La forma apropiada de añadir botones a un mensaje en Discord es a través de vistas. Estos son los pasos a seguir:

1. Crea el botón ([`discord.ui.Button`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20button#discord.ui.Button))
2. Asociale al botón una [`callback`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20button#discord.ui.Button.callback), que es la interacción a realizar por el bot cuando se seleccione el botón.
3. Crea la vista ([`discord.ui.View`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20button#discord.ui.View)) que encapsule al botón.
4. Añade el botón a la vista haciendo uso del método [`add_item()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20button#discord.ui.View.add_item)
5. Al mandar el mensaje, añade la vista haciendo uso del parámetro `view`.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command(name="button_test")
async def button_test(ctx : commands.Context):
    
    async def my_callback(interaction : discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Respuesta de prueba")

    button = discord.ui.Button(label="TEST")
    button.callback = my_callback

    view = discord.ui.View()
    view.add_item(button)
    await ctx.send(content="Mensaje con botón", view=view)
```